# Argument/Parameter names in R - problems with local variables

Tags: r, function, parameters, global, local

I have written many functions in R and I sometimes get issues with global and local variables. To be more precise, if I have the following global variables and function:

```
# Defined before function, globally:
ret <- 0.12314
fa <- 789989.938

prasx <- function(ret, fa, ctry, arb, x = "4"){
# do some stuff...
return (yxc)
}
```

Then I call the function via:

```
prasx(ret, fa, 'US', 3874.38) # OR
prasx('US', 3874.38)
```

I sometimes get errors. Obviously I think it happens if the global variables are not initialized after a workspace wipe.

I'd like to know if this is a good way of writing functions in R, or if you would better use different argument/parameter names for functions than global variable names.
Very often you just want to forward the global variable to the function; that's why I usually give them equal names. Also I guess it's always safer to avoid the below function call, without specifications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with "global" or "local" variables, per se. I think you're just confused about how function calls evaluate their arguments.

You've defined a function with 5 arguments:

```
prasx <- function(ret, fa, ctry, arb, x = "4"){
# do some stuff...
return (yxc)
}
```

The only one with a default value specified is `x`, with a default value of `4`. This means any of the other arguments, if used in the function, must appear in the function call. So calling `prasx('US', 3874.38)` will always generate an error if either `ctry` or `arb` are referenced at any point inside the function. e.g.

```
x <- 4
f <- function(x,y){x}
> f(y = 3)
Error in f(y = 3) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

That last bit might have confused you, because you probably thought you were passing `'US'` to the argument `ctry`, but you are not. R evaluates function arguments in three steps. First, by exact matching on argument name, then partial matching on argument name, and finally by position. Since you didn't name either argument in `prasx('US', 3874.38)`, R interpreted that as equivalent to `prasx(ret = 'US',fa = 3874.38)`. (See [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching).)

Your first example function call would be equivalent to this:

```
prasx(ret = ret,fa = fa,ctry = 'US',arb = 3874.38)
```

When programming (as opposed to working interactively at the console) it is almost always better to call your functions using their full, named arguments. It is easier to read, less error prone and easier to debug.

Comment: thanks! Now I got it :) I cannot vote you up because I dont have the sufficient reputation :/